# Connect to mysql via SSH2 without an open port

Tags: mysql, linux, ssh

I have a server which I can connect to via SSH, this server is running mysql. I don't have access via port 3306. Many years ago I got around this using SSH tunnelling but can't get it working at the moment. The steps I thought I used where

1) Connect to a command prompt on the server via putty
2) Issue some command to setup the tunnel
3) Connect MySQL Workbench via 127.0.0.1 which would forward packets to the server.

It's step 2 that is causing me problems. I am connecting from windows to Enterprise Linux 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what is exactly the answer. But I suggest to look at the following.

```
use plink.exe
```

or use the following link to set up tunnel from windows to linux.

```
https://howto.ccs.neu.edu/howto/windows/ssh-port-tunneling-with-putty/
```